# Handling empty sets in relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

Let A consist of all 8 subsets of the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$, that is

> A = $\{ \phi , \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, ...\}$

The relation $R$ on $A$ is defined by:

> $aRb$ iff **some** element of $a$ is larger than  **some** element of $b$.

My question is, is $(\phi,\{1\})$ an element of $R$?

My answer is no, because there simply is no element of $\phi$. Similarly,  $(\{1\}, \phi)$ is not in $R$. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct.  This is a fundamental idea about the empty set that always deserves a stop and check.

> $aRb$ iff **some** element of $a$ is larger than  **some** element of $b$.

So is there an element of $\emptyset$ that is larger than an element of $\{1\}$?  As you say, no.

By contrast, if the rule had been

> $aRb$ iff **all** elements of $a$ are larger than  **all** elements of $b$.

then $(\emptyset,\{1\})\in R$ vacuously true because there isn't an element of $\emptyset$ that is a counterexample to the definition.